# hive metastrore (COLUMNS_V2) for azure databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, hive-metastore

I have configured Hive Version 2.3.0 in azure sql database on DBR 10.X. I can see entries all delta tables in dbo.TBLS however [dbo].[COLUMNS_V2] shows only one entry per table which is like below..

| CD_ID | COMMENT | COLUMN_NAME | TYPE_NAME | INTEGER_IDX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 346 | from deserializer | col | array | 0 |

what I am missing here? why don't I see all columns for Table ID-346?

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this same problem and found the cause for my case:

When I wrote data to the hive table in my databricks notebook I had:

```
myDf.write.mode('Delta').saveAsTable('myHiveDb.myTable')
```

This caused the columns to not show up in COLUMNS_V2. Instead you need to change the mode to 'Hive' instead of 'Delta':

```
myDf.write.mode('Hive').saveAsTable('myHiveDb.myTable')
```